# how to divide huge blade file into small parts

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade file that has over 4k sentences, it works well for sure but it is so difficult for me to edit the file and find what I am looking for, hence I am looking for a way to divide this huge file into small parts to make it easy to edit later or any solution for that.

Comment: Read about [Laravel Blade Components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components)

Comment: Yes please go through the https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade do select the Laravel version that you are using for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resources/views/one.blade.php

```php
<div>one</div>
```

---

resources/views/two.blade.php

```php
<div>two</div>
```

---

resources/views/all.blade.php

```php
@include('one')
@include('two')
```

Comment: How you will load script of corresponding div? And how can we load respective div data via ajax?